# How to extract cell values from dataframe to new object with a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, cell

I have two dataframes. One, `dataA`, contains columns `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. The other, `dataB`, is a large matrix (135x240) where in some cells there are probabilities but most cells contain 0. I need to extract cell values from `dataB` and create a new object from them. Indices for the cells to extract are in `dataA`, `X` is the columns, `Y` is the rows, but only if `Z == 1121`.

So far I've tried this, and some variations of it, but nothing works. I'd be very grateful for any and all help.

```
new_object <- dataB %>% 
  for (val in dataA$Z=="1121") {mutate (prob = select(dataB[dataA$Y, dataA$X])}
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R is probably a better choice here:

```
    z_index <- dataA$Z == "1121"
subset_function <- function(x, y, dat) dat[y, x]
X <- dataA$X[z_index]
Y <- dataA$Y[z_index]
new_object <- mapply(FUN = subset_function, x = X, y = Y, MoreArgs = list(dat = dataB))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, that at least works somewhat, though it extracts part of dataB completely while I only need singular cells, i.e., I only need values at [80, 120]  [81, 125] [90, 131]. But if I do it as you suggested I also get values at  [80, 125] and [80, 131] and so on.

Comment: I've updated the code, please let me know if it still doesn't work.